# React Native Create Custom Component/Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, react-native

In React Native, there are certain third-party components which compile their own libraries that can be included in your main React project. Examples of such third-party libraries are these:

- https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-touch-id
- https://github.com/lazaronixon/react-native-qrcode-reader
- https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-modal

Now, I would very much like to create my own React Native component with a linked library (iOS only, so I only need the Cocoa library that I would link using this method: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html), and so far, all I found is this: http://moduscreate.com/react_native_custom_components_ios/

The resulting project does not, however, specify a library target, and is not linkable to a different project.

I have also tried copying the Touch ID repository and try changing that one's code, but alas, I found it to be uncompilable without being referenced from a different project, which in turn would be the one to be compiled.

Where can I find any guides at all regarding how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### 1. Command: new-library

React-native-cli offers the [new-library](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/library/library.js#L64) command:

```
react-native new-library --name <YourNewLibraryName>
```

Calling this will generate a sample library in your `Libraries` directory by copying sample file over from the [react-native library](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/Sample).

#### 2. Developing

React Native has a couple docs specifically for writing [Native Modules](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content) and [Native UI Components](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#content), depending on what you want to achieve.

#### 3. Link component

Link your component once you're done by following the [instructions](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#content) you already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! Bummer about the reputation thing, but your links are much appreciated.

Comment: following up on my question, how do I make the generated library work with Android? There appears to be a lack of necessary Gradle scripts in the generated folder structure.

Comment: I have to admit, that I have no experience with custom components on Android. Sorry!

Comment: I could not find the `new-library` command in `react-native-cli@0.2.0`. Instead, this worked for me within my react-native module: `node ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js new-library --name newlib` ... but then it created it in the wrong directory. Surely there is an easier way?

Comment: As of 2022, it seems to be outdated. Modern approach is described here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the official Facebook guide [Native Modules Setup](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-setup). It explains how to start:

```
$ yarn global add create-react-native-module
$ create-react-native-module MyLibrary
```

This will generate a `README.md` with next steps as follows:

> ### react-native-my-library
>
> #### Getting started
>
> `$ npm install react-native-my-library --save`
>
> Mostly automatic installation
>
> `$ react-native link react-native-my-library`
>
> #### Usage
>
> ```
> import my-library from 'react-native-my-library';
>
> // TODO: What to do with the module? 
> my-library;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [react-native Module setup](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup)

```
$ yarn global add create-react-native-module
$ create-react-native-module NameOfLibrary
```

A template would be generated for you, you can write your custom UI code in the index.js and expand on it as deemed fit.

Answer (score -21):

Create Component in react-native :

```
const App = ( ) => {
  return (
    <Text>Some Text</Text>
  );
}
```

To register this component you should use:

```
ReactNative.AppRegistry.registerComponent('your_project_name', ( ) => App);
```