# How do I add an existing library as dependent on my new library? REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-native-module

I am creating a new library for React Native and I would like to add an existing library that uses native modules as a dependent ([React Native Video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video)) to use my library, but I am not able to do that.

I've seen some posts from GitHub and StackOverFlow on this subject, but they don't answer my question, for example:

- [How do you modify other's library/ module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661536/how-do-you-modify-others-library-module)
- [React Native Create Custom Component/Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353631/react-native-create-custom-component-library)

PS: My library does not use any native modules except the ones that the [react native video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) library already does.